# Minimal number of intersections of families of lines

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm considering two families, $F_1$ and $F_2$, of lines in the plane with $\vert F_1 \vert= N_1$ and $\vert F_2 \vert =N_2$. The families are such that if we pick $g \in F_1$ and $l \in F_2$ we get that the intersection of this two lines is a point. Further we know that at most $n_1$ of the lines in $F_1$ can intersect in a point, and $n_2$ for $F_2$. I'm looking for a lower bound of the number of intersection points.

A trivial lower bound would be 1 but we can not achive this if $n_i < N_i$, since then not all lines can go through the same point. Can we in this case establish a better lower bound dependent on $N_1, N_2, n_1$ and $n_2$?

I tried to state the problem in a more combinatorial way here:
[Minimum for combinatorial sortingproblem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4178881/894890)

But maybe the more geometric version is more appealing for you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [sweep algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) allows to find intersections among segments (Shamos and Hoey alg)